# Should breakpoint in the Page_Load event handler be hit when making AJAX call?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making the following ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'AJAX.aspx/TestPageLoad',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        alert( x.responseText);
    }
});
```

I put a break point in my AJAX.aspx page but it does not get hit. Is it the way it supposed to be? According to [this article](http://www.dotnetperls.com/page-load) it does.

Comment: No. The lifecycle doesn't run on ajax requests. You can only invoke a public static web method from an ajax callback. The example you linked to simply posts to a page instead of invoking a method on a page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I put a breakpoint in the Page_Load of my AJAX.aspx page but it does
>   not get hit

It's because the JavaScript executes on DOM Ready.

> Doesn't Page_Load event get fired when making ajax calls?

No. It executes after Page life cycle and on DOM ready

For that you have to set the debugger in Ajax call like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;                     //A kind of Break Point
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'AJAX.aspx/TestPageLoad',
        data: JSON.stringify({}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert(x.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Then why does the breakpoint get hit when I do this: `$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Ajax.aspx',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            content = $(data).find('div1').html();
        }
    });`? Note that no webmethod name is specified

Comment: @MikeJM : Let me explain it. First, you page life cycle executes, once it is done, the Ajax Queries executes. Then finally, AJAX calls  the server code. Hope this will help you.