# How to debug a WebMethod in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have the following `WebMethod` in my **`fileName.asmx.cs`** file.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetData(string value)
    {
        //-----
        //Respective code querying the database
        //-----
    }
```

Here is the respective ajax call using **`jQuery`**

```
getData: function (type) {        
        var response = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "../GetData",
            data: '{value:' + type.toString() + '}',
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log('succes', msg)
                response = msg;
            }
        });
        return response.d;
    }
```

I add breakpoints in my `WebMethod` for debugging, however it is not stepping into it.
I'm trying to do this my localhost:2133, With reference some SO Answers I also tried attaching the following process but no success.

[image]

Without debugging I'm not able to solve errors, Since I already wasted a couple of hours I posted here.

Can someone guide me(couple of screenshots will be more helpful) **how to debug a WebMethod in ASP.NET?**

**Updates 1:** I also tried putting **`Console.WriteLine()`** in the `WebMethod`.  But nothing shown in the output screen of VS2012.

**Updates 2:** I'm getting error will building the file, but the site is up in my localhost.  Is this error is causing me trouble to debug the WebMethod?  or to be clear

**Only clean code (without error) can only be debugged?**

Comment: Is your ajax call reaching the server, you can check this in the firebug net tab, whether there is succesfull ajax call or not.

Comment: @Bibhu Since I have handled the exception in `WebMethod`.  I'm getting the error response from server (ie, my localhost).  I also tried the same for a successful `WebMethod`, but no success :(

Comment: whats the error you are getting

Comment: @Bibhu I myself doing it (`try..return successJson..catch.."\error\"`) This is also not working for a successful calls.

Comment: @christiandev That is not the issue, because the other method in asmx file is getting the result.  Actually I need to know how to debug the `WebMethod`.  Anyway thanks for pointing it

Comment: @user1671639 what error you are seeing in F12 tab? When you try to hit your webmethod, keep the 'Network'(Chrome) tab opened and se what comes in the response

Comment: @JhonatasKleinkauff Coldn't get you about F12tab.  When I add debug point inside the `webmethod`, it is not stepping into it.

Comment: @christiandev Ok let me make it clear.  Thing I'm getting the value returned from WebMethod, but I'm not to debug it(Adding breakpoint has not effect).  I need to know a way to debug this `WebMethod`.  Hope this is clear.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't realised you were getting data.  OK, so you have the project running in debug mode? are you able to hit other break points?

Comment: @christiandev Yes I'm running the project in DEBUG mode.  I added breakpoints in couple of the other WebMethods.  But none is getting hit.  This is driving me crazy.

Comment: not sure if this is helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072014/should-breakpoint-in-the-page-load-event-handler-be-hit-when-making-ajax-call

Comment: @christiandev My issue is completely in serever(WebService) side, not in Clientcode(JS).  Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do all of my web site debugging in ASP.NET by inserting data into a debug log in my database. This method is very simple and it always works regardless of how your server was called from the client *(because a page load, a call to a web service, and a callback from a page all result in different server functionality and return states)*.

Also, using the Chrome developer tools Network Tab is extremely useful for debugging web methods.

1. Open a page that is going to make a web request
2. Open Chrome's developer tools, go to the network tab
3. Fire the web request. Now you will see a row added to the results in the network tab with the name of the web method and the URL of it. Click on that name and you will see 5 tabs: Headers, Preview, Response, Cookies, and Timing. If your web method threw an error and you have your site setup to display the stack trace on the aspx page, then the 'Response' page will actually show you the rendered error page that was created.

Answer (score 0):

After a long struggle (a whole day), I found what was causing me the issue.  The reason why I was not able to debug is because of 2 errors.

I didn't consider to fix because it was a merely a licence error.  *Now I learnt that only clean (error free code) Web Service can be debugged.*

Whereas for debugging via IIS, I used **`w3wp.exe`** process attaching to it.

This helped me a lot http://forums.iis.net/t/1154992.aspx