# How to add WebMethod in an asmx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have started working in ASPX web project, which has already an existing `asmx` file.  It contains around 4 WebMethods and these 4 Webmethods are showing the `http://localhost:2133/WebServices.asmx`

[image]

Now I tried adding **new WebMethod** named **`GetCities`** very similar to the existing one, but it is not showing the list in `http://localhost:2133/WebServices.asmx`.  I tried recompiling it.  When I checked deeply (service reference)I couldn't find where the WebService **`WebServices.asmx`** is being referenced.

Existing Method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetAvailable(int clientCode)
    {
        try
        {
            //Db Querying statements
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
    }
```

New method I added

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetCities()
    {
        try
        {
           //Db Querying statements 
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {

        }
    }
```

Totally confused, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Restart your visual studio, and then debug again, also close all the existing sessions of VS web server, and then try again. May be it is referencing to the old port for the VS Web server

Comment: @Habib Give me a minute I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Habib I tried restarting the VS but no success.  Still it is not showing.  I too check the port before starting the VS.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you.  Currently I'm working for an existing project using ASMX concepts.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Can you please share thoughts on debugging a `WebMethod` in asmx file, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18721860/1671639. Please ignore if I made a wrong request here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the proxy class that is used to work with your web service by doing the following:

1. In Solution Explorer, open your project's App_WebReferences folder and click the node for the Web reference you want to update.
2. Right-click the reference and click Update Web Reference.
   The new files for the XML Web service are downloaded to your project. Information for the XML Web service is updated within your project.

Read [How to: Update a Project Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf3b21x2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for documentation.

Comment: I couldn't find a folder named App_WebReferences.  But I saw an empty folder named Service Reference.  Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: Where did you add the service reference at?

Comment: Thats my problem, I could find how it is referred.  I couldn't find where it is added.  I am access this WebServices.asmx.

Comment: If you navigate to `http://localhost:2133/WebServices.asmx?wsdl`, does that show the new method?

Comment: Check your service reference in Visual Studio, maybe it's not pointing to that project but to another one.  maybe it's pointing to the qa or production environment rather than your local project.

Answer (score 0):

When you start your project Visual Studio launches "ASP.NET Development Server" to host application. It is not always terminated once you close visual studio, so it may still execute older version of your web service. Try to stop this application or reboot your machine and see if it helps.