# ASMX and ASPX New WebMethods API Function does Not published

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I want to add new Function to My API App.

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetListCOA()
        {
                ProviderBudgetController oProvider = new ProviderBudgetController();
                List<BudgetControllerModel> oResult = oProvider.GetDistinctCOA();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oResult);

        }
```

At ASPX File :

```
        [WebMethod()]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                ProviderBudgetController oProvider = new ProviderBudgetController();
                List<BudgetControllerModel> oResult = oProvider.GetDistinctCOA();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(oResult);
            }
            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
            {
                return "Cancelled.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string source = "BudgetReportRevision -> " + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
                ProviderLogError.Insert(source, ex.ToString());
                return "Error : " + ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

but, when I compile my app, the changes does not affected. 
I can not see my new methods.

[image: Not shown new methods]

Comment: Isn't [WebMethod()] should be [WebMethod] only?

Comment: I have tried both but no effect..

Comment: Try by cleaning & rebuilding the project. If this doesn't fix the issue then it might be  the case that you have published old app earlier and the URL in IIS is configured to point your old files.

Comment: No changes,  I have publish it just now..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add WebMethod in an asmx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726521/how-to-add-webmethod-in-an-asmx-file)

Comment: Have been tried it but still no clue..

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I have restart my pc and still not working...

Comment: I think this is very weird. I create new asmx file and copy paste all my methods all methods now showing at api List..

Comment: You should check markup file instead of code file. You may find something there.