# ASPX Page Life Cycle when calling [WebMethod]s

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, page-lifecycle

I'm calling a number of methods that have been decorated with [WebMethod] via jQuery ajax.

These require a database connection to be set up in an external library that will be the same for each method.

My original code looked like this:

```
public partial class Server : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code to set up DB connections
        ExternalLibrary.SetupDB(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string AjaxAccessibleMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            // get some data from the database via the external library
            ExternalLibrary.CallDatabase();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

This was working, but then started throwing exceptions claiming that the ExternalLibrary's database hadn't been initialized.

Placing breakpoints in my code I found that the Page_Load event wasn't being called when calling my AjaxAccessibleMethod, I also tried moving the DB setup stuff into the Page_Init event but likewise that wasn't called.

Can anyone explain to me the aspx page life cycle when using WebMethods? The fact that this worked initially seems to imply that Page_Load was called, but it no longer is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18072090/885626

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that the method you are using as WebMethod is static, this should be the first hint to the fact that Page object is not created at all.

Page Methods is a simple alternative to full blown web services, and as such, its life cycle is more similar to web service than to page. That is, request goes through the general ASP.NET pipeline, with objects like HttpContext, Request and such. But then the difference happens: for page requests and postbacks page object is created and the whole series of page events happens, whereas for page methods page object is not created, and method is simply called as `Server.AjaxAccessibleMethod()`.

There is really no way to mix the two, because this would unnecessarily complicate processing of calls to page methods. So the only path forward for you here is duplicate necessary code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // code to set up DB connections
    ExternalLibrary.SetupDB(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public static string AjaxAccessibleMethod()
{
    ExternalLibrary.SetupDB();
    ...
}
```

Comment: how about adding "ExternalLibrary.SetupDB();" in a static constructor ?
That way i think code duplication can be avoided.

Comment: @Boney, I wouldn't recommend using static constructor. The problem here is that you have absolutely no control on when it is going to be called. So it can happen too early for OP's needs. Besides, current code calls it once per request, and at least in case of page methods you cannot be certain this is going to happen with static c'tor

Comment: Thanks Andrei, What your saying makes perfect sense. But it still leaves me scratching my head over why this did work... and whats worrying me is that I have used this pattern elsewhere (and it works) - is there any mechanism that you are aware of that might allow this to happen, eg calling the page (rather than a [WebMethod]) and then subsequently calling the [WebMethod]?

Comment: @Morvael, I am not aware of such mechanism, and I'd love to see the case when it is happening - the explanation might be a bit different.

Comment: @Andrei, I've just been digging a bit deeper into the ExternalLibrary. It seems that the SetupDB() stuff is all static, and can persist between page calls. So it looks like, in this case, calling it once will be OK until the website re-compiles (i'm guessing), which explains why it sometimes works. Calling it each time seems to be the only reliable solution. Thanks again.