# VB.NET code behind doesn't get the data from AJAX request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, asp.net-ajax

I would be happy if you could help me. I have a problem getting data in Page_Load that should come from AJAX request. I do an AJAX request:

```
$.post({
            url: 'pdf.aspx',
            //data: { ID: '1833' },
            data: 'id=1833',
            dataType: 'text',
            type: 'post',   
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',

            success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                console.log("sssss " + data);
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                console.log("fffff " + msg);
            },
            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

And I have code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
  Handles Me.Load

    Dim ID = Request.Form("id")
    Response.Write(ID)

End Sub
```

As a result I get nothing to ID variable. I tried all possible options, but still have a problem. Any ideas? Thank you for any answer!

Comment: `type: "POST", url: "pdf.aspx", dataType: "json", data: {id: 1833}` up top should be all you need. I have that format (with different url of course) on a page I just tested and Request.Form("id") held the intended value

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer! I did what you told me, but I have SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Qb (jquery.min.js:4)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="VisualBasicWebForm.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#theBtn").click(function () {
                $.post({
                    url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetData',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //using get all textbox selector-you can use a different selector
                    data: '{ID: "' + $(":text").attr("ID") + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                        //don't forget the .d
                        alert("sssss " + data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="passToServer" />
            <input type="button" id="theBtn" value="Go" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is your code behind:

```
Imports System.Web.Services

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetData(ByVal ID As String) As String
    'Dim ID = Request.Form("id")
    'Response.Write(ID)
    'Instead of the above, you can put a breakpoint on the next line to see value of ID

    'Also returning ID so it is display, in your case sent to console.log
    Return ID
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I can't use web methods in  my project :(

Comment: What do you mean you "can't" use them? If you want a response back, then this is the right way to do it. An ajax post isn't even going to hit your page_load handler, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072014/should-breakpoint-in-the-page-load-event-handler-be-hit-when-making-ajax-call) for an explanation of why.

Comment: I mean that in code behind I need to create a pdf file and to store data in it. If I remember well, I can't work with iTextSharp in a web method. May be I am wrong?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use iTextSharp from inside a webmethod? Just because the function is a web method doesn't mean it can't access your project references

Comment: because web method is a static one

Comment: Well I just made a test project, added iTextSharp to the project, and created an empty pdf document from inside a webmethod successfully. I don't know what to tell you, other than it is possible. It looks like you have an answer showing you how use ajax to post data to a web method, and you can make your pdf inside the webmethod, seems like you have all you need to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @soohoonigan, Thank you very much for your help!